# How to compile c programming calling python2.7 functions

Tags: python

I am calling python function from c programmings. I am able to compile and linked for 2.6 using below command

```
gcc py_sample.c -I/usr/include/python2.6 -lpython2.6 ;
```

But the requirement is python2.7. Kindly help how to compile and link together in gcc command. i tried the below command but still facing issue.

```
gcc -I/usr/local/inlcude/python2.7  -ldl /usr/lib64/python2.7 -Wall -fPIC py_sample.c -lpython2.7

/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tmpnam':
/tmp/Python-2.7/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7275: warning: the use of `tmpnam_r' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tempnam':
/tmp/Python-2.7/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7230: warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(signalmodule.o): In function `timeval_from_double':
/tmp/Python-2.7/./Modules/signalmodule.c:112: undefined reference to `floor'
/tmp/Python-2.7/./Modules/signalmodule.c:112: undefined reference to `floor'
/tmp/Python-2.7/./Modules/signalmodule.c:113: undefined reference to `fmod'
/tmp/Python-2.7/./Modules/signalmodule.c:113: undefined reference to `fmod'
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(floatobject.o): In function `float_is_integer':
/tmp/Python-2.7/Objects/floatobject.c:976: undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(floatobject.o): In function `float_as_integer_ratio':
/tmp/Python-2.7/Objects/floatobject.c:1711: undefined reference to `floor'
```

Comment: Did you forget `-lm` as the last option for the linker, to include the math-library?

Comment: gcc -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7 -Wall -fPIC py_sample.c -o samp -lpython2.7 -lm;     executed this command. is it right ? still facing same issue

Answer (score 3):

Iskren has given you the fix to your specific problem.  I am here with the general case of finding out what the flags need to be.

According to [Compiling and Linking under Unix-like systems](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems), Python will tell you what compiling and linking options are recommended for your system through the use of the Python `pythonX.Y-config` command (where X and Y represent the version you have.)  With `--cflags` and `--ldflags` being used to request the compiling and linking flags.

The link gives examples for Python 2.7

```
$ /opt/bin/python2.7-config --cflags
-I/opt/include/python2.7 -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

$ /opt/bin/python2.7-config --ldflags
-L/opt/lib/python2.7/config -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

Comment: $ /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config --ldflags    => -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic               and     $/usr/local/bin/python2.7-config --cflags=>-I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes                           and my gcc command is " gcc -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config -ldl -lpython2.7 -lm py_sample.c"   where is i made a mistake. kindly help me.

Answer (score 2):

Given you have a working installation of python-2.7 installed in /usr/local,
you'll need to do some tweaks:

Fix this typo:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/in**lc**ude/python2.7
```

Explicitly specify the library path (on a correctly configured system it should work by default, but we don't know that and it doesn't hurt): `-L/usr/local/lib -lpython2.7` (add **64** suffix to lib if needed)

Link with the math library that defines `floor` and `pow`: `-lm`

Your final command should be something like:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -ldl -lpython2.7 -lm py_sample.c
```

Comment: execute the same     " gcc -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config -ldl -lpython2.7 -lm py_sample.c"     still facing py_sample.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `Py_SetProgramName'
py_sample.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'